# Запятая перед что

Tags: пунктуация

Здравствуйте.

> вот что я понял

Нужна ли запятая перед "что"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Вот что я понял.***

Запятая после частицы *вот* не нужна. Это частица, в данном случае совмещающая значение акцентирования со значением указательности (вот, вон). Ср.: *Вот это я понял.*